# Matching urls without specific delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all the URLs inside an arbitrary text, with no specific delimiters, and eventually with multiple items in the same line:

```
http://www.site.com/image1.jpg "http://www.site.com/image2.jpg"
'http://www.site.com/image1.jpg&a=1'
```

Please not the space after the fist URL, and the terminating `&a=1`

This is my actual regex: `(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))`, that matches correctly just the last URL, but the fist and second are matched as one result.

The expected result should be instead this:

```
http://www.site.com/image1.jpg
http://www.site.com/image2.jpg
http://www.site.com/image1.jpg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if they are all ending with .jpg it's fairly easy to achieve with this regexp: `/[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.-]+\.jpg/`. 
I've added few more url examples to test the match. The result is an array of matches.

```
var str = "http://www.site.com/image1.jpg \"http://www.site.com/image2.jpg\" 'http://www.site.com/image1.jpg&a=1' http://www.21d1dk1kk1.org/image.jpg http://www.21d1dk1-kk1.org/image.jpg";

var matches = str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.-]+\.jpg/g);
```

if you need to match more then just jpg you can use `(jpg|gif|png)` etc. in place of the jpg (eg. `[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.-]+\.(jpg|gif|png)/g`)

Having the array of matches you can output it whatever way you want by iterating it. But I assume you know how to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks, works great! Have modified the regex like this: `var items = ht.match(/https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9:\/\.-]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/gi);` to match absolute URLs, multiple file types and case insensitive.

Comment: yeah - didn't know if you need the protocol or not :) but glad it was usefull, cheers!